# Flash CS5.5 Iphone App OTA distribution and or sync without removing apps

Tags: iphone, ios, flash-cs5

I've been having some fun with Flash developing IOS apps. I currently have two devices provisioned but each device is synced with a different iTunes account. My work iPad and personal iPhone.

I'm currently using my work iPad as the testing device. Adding the .ipa to iTunes and syncing. It works great.

I would like to be able to add the .ipa file to my iPhone too, but iTunes will erase all my apps in order to sync and I don't want that.

Is there anyway to get around this?

Can I go about this using the over the air wireless distribution method? Flash has publish settings for adhoc deployment does this deal with OTA? Also don't you need a .plist file and to get OTA to work?

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Tegan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to distribute flash created IPAs using adhoc OTA distribution. Apple has information on creating the necessary manifest plist [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html). You do not need an enterprise developer account for this to work but you will need access to a web server to host the files and talk to the apple servers (this can be hosted locally). Once everything is set up you can visit the web server from your iPhone and download the app. We distribute internal testing builds using this system and it functions very nicely.